# How to add an array within a foreach in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to insert data from a form which i get it in the form of an array and i am using a foreach to insert the data each in to the database. amongst these data i have another array that i need to insert it in the form of an array.

The Amendities should be saved in the form of an array! i tried using implode but didn't quite get the results i expected.

```
foreach ($request->room_type as $item => $v) {
        $data2 = array(
            'room_type' => $request->room_type[$item],
            'no_of_pax' => $request->no_of_pax[$item],
            'no_of_pax_children' => $request->no_of_pax_children[$item],
            'cost_per_adult' => $request->cost_per_adult[$item],
            'cost_per_child' => $request->cost_per_child[$item],
            'room_description' => $request->room_description[$item],
            'amendities' => implode($request->amendities),
            'hotel_id' => $hotel->id,
        );

        dd($data2);
        Rooms::insert($data2);
    }
```

impoding Amendities array saves the data as a string but i am trying to get the values as an array.

Comment: how are you planning on trying to save an array in the database?

Comment: @lagbox row by row! expect for the amendities which should be an array. gives me an array to string conversion error trying to do so!

Comment: right, because how could you store an array in a database field? what type of field would that be?

Comment: @lagbox a string?

Comment: right, so you would have to save it as a string of some sort, and a string isn't an array

Comment: yes, that is why i used impode to save the data as string values. isn't it possible for me to save the data as an array? an alternate way atleast?

Comment: you would need to then explode that string after retrieving it, then you would have an array ... otherwise there is JSON and model attribute casting

Comment: @lagbox thank you the json method just worked great for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help guys this is final solution which worked for as per your help

```
foreach ($request->room_type as $item => $v) {
        $opt = array(
            'room_type' => $request->room_type[$item],
            'no_of_pax' => $request->no_of_pax[$item],
            'no_of_pax_children' => $request->no_of_pax_children[$item],
            'cost_per_adult' => $request->cost_per_adult[$item],
            'cost_per_child' => $request->cost_per_child[$item],
            'room_description' => $request->room_description[$item],
            'amendities' => json_encode($request->amendities),
            'hotel_id' => $hotel->id,
        );
        array_push($data2, $opt);
    }

    Rooms::insert($data2);
```

Thank you for your help all of you!

Answer (score 0):

u need to prepare a datasets to insert multiple record
so u can try like this

```php
$data2 = [];
foreach ($request->room_type as $item => $v) {
         $opt = array(
                'room_type' => $request->room_type[$item],
                'no_of_pax' => $request->no_of_pax[$item],
                'no_of_pax_children' => $request->no_of_pax_children[$item],
                'cost_per_adult' => $request->cost_per_adult[$item],
                'cost_per_child' => $request->cost_per_child[$item],
                'room_description' => $request->room_description[$item],
                'amendities' => json_encode($request->amendities),
                'hotel_id' => $hotel->id,
            );
         array_push($data2,$opt);
}
Rooms::insert($data2);
```

Comment: i am getting the array values saved into the database properly. my problems here is this part ( amendities' => implode($request->amendities) i need to save an array here instead of a string. and thank you for your approach of using foreach.

Comment: can u show `$request->amendities` what is coming in this .?

Comment: i get an array. something like this                                                                       
  array:6 [▼
  0 => "towels"
  1 => "option1"
  2 => "option2"
  3 => "option3"
  4 => "option3"
  5 => "option3"
]

Comment: i need to store it as an array but the problem is when i directly try to use the request->amendities way i get an array to string conversion error!

Comment: u can encode into json and save `json_encode($request->amendities)` like that u can't story array into database

Comment: can you post this  json_encode($request->amendities as an answer so that i can make it as a solution